# Optimise SQL Script with multiple joins on the same table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a search query that is slow, takes around 28 seconds to run. I want to decrease its running time to under 1 second, I am sure the reason it is slow might have to do with the way I'm Inner Joining multiple times the same table.

Any advice that can point me in the right direction is most appreciated.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  wp_posts.ID,
  wp_posts.post_title

FROM wp_posts

  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id AND ( mt1.meta_key = 'wpcm_frdate' AND mt1.meta_value IN ('2017','2018','2014') ))
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id AND ( mt2.meta_key = 'vehicle_type' AND mt2.meta_value IN ('HATCHBACK','SEDAN') ) )
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt3 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt3.post_id AND ( mt3.meta_key = 'vehicle_transmission' AND mt3.meta_value IN ('AUTOMATIC','MANUAL','DSG') ) )
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt4 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt4.post_id AND ( mt4.meta_key = 'symbol' AND mt4.meta_value IN ('!','%','*') ) )
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt5 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt5.post_id AND ( mt5.meta_key = 'stock_code'   AND mt5.meta_value IN ('2020','3380','4563','12063') ))
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt6 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt6.post_id AND ( mt6.meta_key = 'wpcm_mileage' AND CAST(mt6.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '0'  AND '305000' ))
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt7 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt7.post_id AND ( mt7.meta_key = 'wpcm_price'   AND CAST(mt7.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '0'  AND '1500000' )
                                     AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'wpcm_make'    AND wp_postmeta.meta_value  IN ('68','74') ))
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt8 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt8.post_id AND ( mt8.meta_key = 'wpcm_model'   AND mt8.meta_value IN ('84','75','151','69','91','223','247','70') ) )
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt9 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt9.post_id AND ( ( mt9.meta_key = 'wpcm_condition' AND mt9.meta_value IN ('new','pre-owned','top-marques') )))
WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'wpcm_vehicle' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))

GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC;
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?? Tag only relevent RDBMS

Comment: It would be useful to see the structure of the tables - and indexes.

Comment: Is this query right ? You select ID and post_title but group by ID only. This query will fail.

Comment: this is a working query ?

Comment: Why you use self join but not using the self join tables on either the select or the where? can't you just use where clause?

Comment: looks to me like a `EAV` design.

Comment: @ShakeerMirza It's MySQL

Comment: I see the point of the inner joins mt1 to mt9 (although I might have gone for EXISTS in the WHERE statement myself); but I do not understand why the very first JOIN is there.  What exactly does that add?  Your performance is also going to depend a lot on the indexes you've defined.  Sharing those will help.

Comment: @Koen I have not defined any custom indexes yet, there is a BTREE index on post_id

Comment: @Nick I have not defined any custom indexes yet, there is  a BTREE Index on meta_key

Comment: @Jayjay You could try adding 'CREATE INDEX myIndex ON wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key)'.  After also removing the first join, it would be nice to get the result from running EXPLAIN SELECT...

Comment: @Koen the first join I need for my compare statement `AND wp_posts.post_type = 'wpcm_vehicle' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))` and you are right defining an index solved this issue.

Comment: @Jayjay not the one I meant.  I meant the 'INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )' line.  I fail to see the point.  As far as I can see you're not using it anywhere else.